# Replacing Postcodes with numbers if in

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am looking to have an sql query in one statement which pulls through a postcode, if its within that postcode to then replace that one with the wording test.

```
For example:
SELECT [Postcode]
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE user = 'user'
AND [Postcode] IN ('000 000')

SELECT REPLACE
('{[postcode]}'
,'000 000','test data')
```

I am thinking about using nested SQL. Is there anyway I can join the two above statements into one?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT --[Postcode], 
  case when [PostCode] = '000 000' then REPLACE([Postcode],'000 000','test data') else [PostCode] end as [Postcode]
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE user = 'user'
--AND [Postcode] IN ('000 000')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks however is there a way I can add multiple postcodes? and if the postcodes are not within '000 000' will this then be ignored and the statement will pull through the normal postcodes instead of continuing?

Comment: Check the updated query, I think you are looking this condition in case statement

Comment: Ah ok, how do we add in multiple post codes? :) it works but this is only for one, but we have around 40 to add lol

Comment: There is space in between 3 zeroes so you cannot convert it to int, if still you want to convert to int then you need to replace(postcode,' ', '').. But if you want this why you are converting to 000 000 in first place?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? The code you gave works correctly :) as described. However we just need to add multiple post codes to it? :)

Comment: If you have 40+ columns you can generate for onetime using information_schema.columns where table_name = 'yourtable'

Comment: Sorry what do you mean information_Schema ect? Also is there a way we can make it conditional in the sense that if it exists it takes one route if not another? :)

Comment: Never mind any how you need to write conditions like this, i mentioned you can generate using information_schema

Comment: Ah ok, I will have a look. Any idea how to add multiple postcodes to your statement? :)